# Google App Engine - Retrieve instances of classes which are derived from base class

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In my GAE project, I have a base class called Part.
From this class I derive other classes such as Motor and Battery.

If I run the following:

```
motors   = Motor.query().fetch()
batterys = Battery.query().fetch()
```

I will get all the parts, but I am looking for something more elegant.
If I run:

```
parts    = Part.query().fetch()
```

I get an empty list [ ].

How can I run the above query and get all results in one list?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but all your Parts classes must inherit from PolyModel

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass

So

```
class Part(ndb.PolyModel):
  #stuff

class Motor(Part):
  # stuff

class Wheel(Part):
  # stuff

parts = Part.query().fetch()
```

However all items are stored in the datastore as Part, they have an additional `classes` attribute which names each of the classes in it's inheritance heirarchy.  Then when the entity is retrieved the correct sub class is instantiated.

Another potential downside, the property names in the stored model are a union of all subclasses, if you have default values for any of the properties. I haven't checked to see how far this goes.  So if you have lots of very different properties in all the subclasses you could be storing a lot of empty properties, and incur the cost of storing all the property names in each entity.

Answer (score 1):

The datastore has no concept of inheritance, and doesn't know that your entity types derive from Part.

There isn't really any way of doing this sort of thing with GAE: ancestor keys are not really the answer, as they would have *all* Motor/Battery entities descending from a single Part, which would severely limit update rates.

The best way to model this kind of relationship would really be to drop the separate models and have a single Part model, with a `part_type` field that can be `"motor"` or `"battery"`.

Comment: Whilst the datastore doesn't have this capability, PolyModel does provide such a facility.